# Kali Linux video player?

Tags: linux, video, media-player

I want to view some videos in .mp4 format using **Kali Linux**. Before I dedicate the time and bandwidth for downloading, I would like to know if Kali offers a *decent video player*.

I would prefer if it's *already installed* since I would be using a Live USB without persistence. If I need to use persistence, that is fine.

The player needs to be able to smoothly play files around **400-550Mb, HD 1080p, 30fps, MP4 format.**

Thanks in advance!

Note: If I must download a player, I would prefer not to use VLC but am willing to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

VLC isn’t just a media player — it's a complete Swiss Army Knife for digital videos and music, and that's why VLC is installed in Kali Linux 2.0 by default. For people who didn't find it just type:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

You can also start vlc in minimized form without all of its usual menus and buttons using the following command. Open the terminal and type:

```
cvlc <path/to/video/file>
```

...where for `<path/to/video/file>` substitute the full path to the video file that you want to play. The video file will start to play automatically.

`cvlc` is already installed with VLC in Kali Linux 2.0 by default. In addition to the default `vlc` skin, the following other skins are also installed with vlc: `qvlc`, `svlc`, `nvlc`, `rvlc`, `cvlc`

Comment: Is there no other player on Kali? It's great to hear that Kali has VLC pre installed, but I wouldn't need to use all the bells and whistles. My biggest issue I have with VLC is the clunkiness I find in it and the interface (I'm a little picky ;D ). +1 for letting me know it's installed

Comment: try cvlc ... what is clunkieness?

Comment: @user1133275 I haven't even heard of cvlc until now; it looks pretty good. I'm used to command line video players since I use Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi. By clunkiness I mean that the interface just looks "crowded" if that makes sense. So, cvlc would be perfect. Is it already installed with vlc or is it a download?